# ES6 class properties with getter and setter not mapped to Asp.net Web API call input

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm passing a javascript object which is defined as a class that has constructor and getter, setter properties. When I pass this object in a POST request to my Asp.net Web Api method, there's no data being passed for the properties that have getter & setter, whereas the data is being passed for all the other properties that do not have getter/setter. What am I doing wrong?

Example:

```
class myObj = {
    constructor(){
        this.normalArray = [1, 2];        
    }

    get arrayWithGetterSetter(){
        return this._arrayWithGetterSetter;
    }

    set arrayWithGetterSetter(value){
        this._arrayWithGetterSetter = value;
    }
}

//Somewhere else in the code
var apiInput = new myObj();
apiInput.arrayWithGetterSetter = [3,4,5];

//ajax Post apiInput to /api/ApiCall
```

Asp.net Web api method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult ApiCall(MyObj input){
    //input.NormalArray has values [1,2]

    //input.ArrayWithGetterSetter is null
}
```

Comment: `When I pass this object in a POST request` and where does this magic happen? note: `ArrayWithGetterSetter` is not the same as `arrayWithGetterSetter`

Comment: I use angularjs $http service for POST.

The web api handles json formatting with Newtonsoft Json formatter which is case insensitive, but anyway I also tried changing it to `arrayWithGetterSetter` but still the value is null

Comment: When i check what's being sent in the request through the Chrome dev tools, the property `arrayWithGetterSetter` is not being sent, but `_arrayWithGetterSetter` is being sent in the request